# SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce

I have a problem with crawling after installing Sitecore commerce. SOLR works, mom is set in CommerceMinions application:

```
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrSearchPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr",
        "SolrUrl": "https://localhost:8983/solr,
        "ConnectionTimeout": -1,
        "SolrDateTimeFormatString": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'",
        "IsSolrCloud": "false",
        "UseSolrAuthentication": false,
        "SolrUserName": "",
        "SolrPassword": ""
      },
```

However, errors appear in the logs all the time:

```
00034 10:47:15 WARN CtxMsg.Warning.MinionProcessingSameEntities: Text=Minion 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.DeleteIndexDocumentsMinion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search' didn't run. There is a minion processing the same type of entities in the 'HabitatMinions' environment running.
00034 10:47:15 WARN CtxMsg.Warning.MinionProcessingSameEntities: Text=Minion 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.IncrementalIndexMinion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search' didn't run. There is a minion processing the same type of entities in the 'HabitatMinions' environment running.
00013 10:47:15 ERROR SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist.Error: Message=<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr//admin/cores. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
|Trace=   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Commands.CoreCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.Send(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status(String coreName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContext.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr//admin/cores. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Commands.CoreCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.Send(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status(String coreName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContext.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
00008 10:47:15 ERROR SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist.Error: Message=<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr//admin/cores. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
|Trace=   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Commands.CoreCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.Send(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status(String coreName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContext.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrContextCommand.DoesIndexExist(String name, CommerceContext context)
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr//admin/cores. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`Sitecore` in version `10.1`, `SOLR` in version `8.4.0`.
In CM and XConnect I have same link and everything work. Do you have any ide what i can do it with this?

**Update**
I thing that problem is /solr//admin/cores. This query not working with SOLR, but /solr/admin/cores is fine. Unfortunately, I don't know what the reason is. I have the SOLR address without the / at the end

Comment: did you try inedxing with Postman? See if you are getting same issue from there as well?

Comment: No working - in logs I have same errors